# How can I use GREP to find all text between bullet and equals sign in bullet list in InDesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign, grep

I have a bulleted list with several entries, it's a list of keyboard shortcuts, similar to the text below:

> - alt+shift+ctrl+2 = Lock Others
> - alt+shift+ctrl+3 = Hide Others
> - alt+ctrl+b = Blend

I want to select all the text between the bullet and the equals symbol, no matter how many characters. Thought this:

```
(?<=•).+?(?=\=)
```

would work, but no luck.

Comment: Are the bullet characters in the actual text, or are they added via a bullets and numbering paragraph style? If it's the latter, I seem to remember trying something similar and being frustrated that the added characters weren't included in the GREP as if they weren't part of the paragraph (or maybe they *were* included - either way, it wasn't what I wanted...).

Answer (score 1):

If you used e.g. a hyphen as the bullet, the expression would probably match as you desire. The bullet is a unicode (hex U+2022) or Ansi (149; hex 95), so try replacing the bullet glyph with `\x{95}` in your regular expression.

EDIT:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/indesign/cs/using/WSFB3603CC-8D84-48d8-9F77-F3E0644CB0B6a.html

I see that the bullet is `~8` when working with regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Well, non of the above seemed to work, likely due to how InDesign does bullets, but this

```
^(.*)(?=\=)
```

seemed to work for what I needed. Thanks for helping though!

Comment: Note that that will match *anything* with an equals sign, so be careful. I found a reference that says inDesign uses `~8`  as a metacharacter for regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

If you use tabs for the spaces, this would work:

```
\t(\s|.*)\t
```

It would include the first tab, followed by all characters until the next tab.

Answer (score 0):

.+\= 
this expression will select all text from the beginning of a line of text up to the equal sign
Then set a character style to format the text as required.
If the Bullets uses a Paragraph Style independent of other text in the document and the bullets are in the style then set a Character Style for the bullet point, 
This means the text formatted with GREP and the bullet can have different character styles